# Object from module sees private variable from class

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know if I'm doing wrong, but I think this is not normal. 
I have class `clsPerson`

```
Private pNameFirst As String

Public Property Get NameFirst() As String
     NameFirst = pNameFirst
End Property
Public Property Let NameFirst(sNameFirst As String)
     pNameFirst = sNameFirst
End Property
```

Now in Module I have procedure `test`

```
Sub test()
    Dim Person As New clsPerson

    Person.NameFirst = "test"
End Sub
```

When I look at Locals and unwrap Person object I can see there my private variable `pNameFirst`.
[image]

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locals window will still display your Private variables from the class. What you can't do in the module is alter the value directly of the private variable.

The locals window will show all your declared variables and ignore scope.

Edit:

See further discussion here:

[Should I have to have duplicate values in VBA class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321263/should-i-have-to-have-duplicate-values-in-vba-class-objects)